# How do you disable speakers but enable headphones in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, audio, speakers

My computer has internal speakers.  I want it to never play sound from the speakers, but I want my headphones to work.  How do I do that?

Comment: what kind of computer, what OS?

Comment: ThinkCentre.  It is Windows 7.

Answer (score 5):

If you have a speaker icon in your notification area you should be able to right click on it and goto Playback Devices. From there you can right click on your speakers and disable them.

Comment: Not all sound drivers allow that. Some combine speakers and headphones, especially on laptops.

Comment: Maybe older ones, I haven't seen that in a while. True though, if it is that type of setup then they won't appear as separate devices here.

Comment: Nope, my new dv6T-7000 has speakers and headphones combined

Comment: Mine are combined.

Comment: I have never seen a computer on which they are not combined.